# E4X XML filtering and only one result

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

Consider this XML:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <subNode>123</subNode>
        <anotherNode>abc</anotherNode>
    </node>
    <node>
        <anotherNode>abc</anotherNode>
    </node>
</root>
```

This works, because E4X only finds 1 match, and returns an XML instead of an XMLList:

```
trace(myXml.node.subNode); // 123
```

But why this throws an `Error #1065: Variable subNode is not defined`?

```
trace(myXml.node.(subNode == 123).anotherNode);
```

Why doesn't it trace `<anotherNode>abc</anothernode>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the player tries to find `subNode` in each `node`, and it can’t, so a [`ReferenceError`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/ReferenceError.html) exception is thrown.

In this case you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29) method to ensure that the property exists:

```
trace(myXml.node.(hasOwnProperty("subNode") && subNode == 123).anotherNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test it, it seems the second node hasn't the subNode.  So try to add subNode(though I think there should be another way to solve this).

```
<root>
   <node>
       <subNode>123</subNode>
       <anotherNode>abc</anotherNode>
    </node>
    <node>
        <subNode>321</subNode>
        <anotherNode>abc</anotherNode>
    </node>
</root>
```

Comment: It's obvious the second node hasn't got a subNode, that's exactly my point. I know it doesn't work because E4X only finds one result, and in consequence it returns an XML instead of XMLList. My question is why that affects the filtering capacities of E4X.